# Nginx для мульти-стрима, как изменить фпс и разрешение на выходе?

Tags: javascript, nginx

По [гайду](https://youtu.be/xdQSzeOhJMo) сделал настроил nginx для трансляции на twitch и steam. На сам nginx видеоряд идет с OBS. Это работает, однако с OBS на nginx я отправляю в качестве 720р и 30fps, а на twitch и steam приходят в качестве 1080р и 60fps

Пытался гуглить, но явного ответа на это не нашел, как изменить выходное fps и качество?

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        push rtmp://live-arn.twitch.tv/app/{mykey};
                        push rtmp://upload.broadcast.sto.steamstatic.com/app/{mykey};
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: по твоему гайду есть место, где явно выставляется качество, пробовал там менять?